# Encoder terminology x1 x2 x4

Tags: encoder, terminology

As a translator from German to English, I'm looking for how English native speakers refer to this behavior of incremental encoders. The German here uses "4x-Auswertung" or "Vierfachauswertung" which translates literally to "4x evaluation". I understand this to be measuring the edge changes of both channels A and B. There is also "1x and 2x evaluation" (measuring just the rising/falling edges of one channel). I have researched the Internet and have found a mötley crüe of suggestions: X4 mode, X4 decoding, X4 resolution, etc. Is there anyone here who works with these who can tell me the right terminology? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: x4 = Quadrature encoder?

Comment: Any people having experience with incremental encoder will understand 4x, X4 MODE, ...all others will not understand nothing, no matter of your effords.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Well.. a professional technical translation should be professional..

Comment: @EugeneSh. Looking at your first comment, I am afraid you're in group of those that aren't familiar with incremental encoders. Anyway, you may give the OP the hint of an professional terminology.

Comment: @Marko: Yes, they will probably know no matter what, but that doesn't mean that I can just write any old thing. Standards matter in my line of work, as does correct and consistent terminology. Nevertheless, I appreciate your input if for no other reason, it takes the pressure off finding the perfect translation if people -- especially internationally -- will understand what is meant immediately with X4 or 4X. Have found in the meantime "quadrature evaluation" and "quadrature decoding" to describe this. Anyone else with any more info?

Comment: @BluegrassWorker They are both quadrature encoders, even the encoder is the same, just the mode is 1x or 4x. As Eugene wrongly said x4 \$\neq\$ Quadrature

Answer (score 1):

x1, x2, x4 **encoding** is commonly used, but most reasonable variations would be understood. English is kind of a free-for-all.

In the case of higher end encoders that have analog sin/cos outputs, it's called interpolation. In the case of the (often German) manufacturers of such encoders, I do note that the newest generation cannot even agree on an interface standard so nomenclature is a pretty minor thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a professional article, then the best way is to rapresent different modes by a timing diagram.
This is how I did it, for 4x mode only:

[image]

Comment: Marko, what language is it? It sound very clear, but written completely differently than how i would write it :)